# How to to route "nested" paths by using `namespace` or `scope :module` / `scope :path`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.2 and I would like to route "nested" paths by using `namespace` or `scope :module` / `scope :path` within the block of a `resource`.

That is, I have the following route:

```
resources :users, :only => [:show]
```

that matches

```
user_path    GET    /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
```

I would like to match the following paths

```
users_sessions_path         POST      /users/sessions              users/sessions#create
user_session_path           GET       /users/:id/session           users/sessions#show
delete_user_session_path    GET       /users/:id/session/delete    users/sessions#delete
user_session_path           DELETE    /users/:id/session           users/sessions#destroy
```

I read the [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and I tried to state something like

```
resources :users, :only => [:show] do
  scope :module => :users do
    scope :module => :sessions do 
    # scope :path => :sessions do
    # namespace :sessions do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

but no attempt has been successful. How should I state routes?

---

**Update** after the @dgilperez answer

I tried the following code

```
resources :users, :only => [:show] do
  scope :module => :users do
    resource :session, :only => [:show, :new, :create, :destroy] do
      get :delete, :on => :collection, :to => 'sessions#delete' 
    end
  end
end
```

that matches

```
delete_user_session_path     GET       /users/:user_id/session/delete(.:format)    users/sessions#delete
new_user_session_path        GET       /users/:user_id/session/new(.:format)       users/sessions#new
user_session_path            POST      /users/:user_id/session(.:format)           users/sessions#create
user_session_path            GET       /users/:user_id/session(.:format)           users/sessions#show
                             DELETE    /users/:user_id/session(.:format)           users/sessions#destroy
```

but I still need to map `new` and `create` actions without needing to pass the `:user_id` parameter. That is, I would like to map something like

```
new_user_session_path        GET       /users/session/new(.:format)       users/sessions#new
user_session_path            POST      /users/session(.:format)           users/sessions#create
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating it: you don't need to use `scope` or `path` to render nested resources. You just nest them:

```
resources :users, :only => [:show] do
  resources :sessions
end
```

will render the following routes:

```
user_sessions     GET    /users/:user_id/sessions(.:format)            sessions#index
                  POST   /users/:user_id/sessions(.:format)            sessions#create
new_user_session  GET    /users/:user_id/sessions/new(.:format)        sessions#new
edit_user_session GET    /users/:user_id/sessions/:id/edit(.:format)   sessions#edit
user_session      GET    /users/:user_id/sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#show
                  PATCH  /users/:user_id/sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#update
                  PUT    /users/:user_id/sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#update
                  DELETE /users/:user_id/sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#destroy
user              GET    /users/:id(.:format)                          users#show
```

Those are not the routes you mention you need, but I'd like you to reconsider if you really need them like that, with namespaced controllers and custom names such as `delete_user_` or you prefer to go more standard. If you really need those exact routes, let me know.

---

**UPDATE** after OP's update

To get the two routes missing you need to get them out the rested resource. I'd just write them directly like this:

```
resources :users, :only => [:show] do
  scope :module => :users do
    resource :session, :only => [:show, :destroy] do
      get :delete, :on => :collection, :to => 'sessions#delete' 
    end
  end
end

get 'users/session/new', to: 'users/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
post 'users/session', to: 'users/sessions#create'
```